# VB6 Print module works fine for Win98 but not working in Win7

Tags: vb6

VB6 Print module works fine for Win98 but not working in Win7. This part of text may be have issues pls give me the solution. Thanks in advance.

---

```
    Function NSPrintFile(PrinterName As String, FileToPrint As String, delAfterPrint As Long) As Long
    Dim I As Long
    Dim Success As Long, phPrinter As Long, Level As Long
    Dim cdBuf As Long, pcbNeeded As Long, JobId As Long
    Dim pPrinterName As String, strJobId As String, strSpoolFile As String
    Dim pDefault As PRINTER_DEFAULTS
    Dim pData As ADDJOB_INFO_1, StartPos As Integer, tmpStartPos As Integer

    pPrinterName = Printer.DeviceName
    Success = OpenPrinter(pPrinterName, phPrinter, pDefault)
    If Success <> 1 Then
        MsgBox "No Printers are installed or Cannot access the Printer !", vbExclamation, "NSPrint"
        NSPrintFile = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    Level = 1
    cdBuf = 64
    pcbNeeded = 0
    pData.Path = String(64, " ")
    Success = AddJob(phPrinter, Level, pData, cdBuf, pcbNeeded)
    If Success <> 1 Then
        MsgBox "Cannot assign JobID !", vbExclamation, "NSPrint"
        NSPrintFile = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    strJobId = Left(pData.Path, 4)
    JobId = Val(Asc(Mid(strJobId, 1, 1))) * 2 ^ 0
    JobId = JobId + Val(Asc(Mid(strJobId, 2, 1))) * 2 ^ 8
    JobId = JobId + Val(Asc(Mid(strJobId, 3, 1))) * 2 ^ 16
    JobId = JobId + Val(Asc(Mid(strJobId, 4, 1))) * 2 ^ 24

    tmpStartPos = 0
    Do Until tmpStartPos = 0 And StartPos <> 0
        tmpStartPos = tmpStartPos + 1
        tmpStartPos = InStr(tmpStartPos, pData.Path, "C:\")
        If tmpStartPos = 0 Then Exit Do
        StartPos = tmpStartPos
    Loop

    strSpoolFile = Mid(pData.Path, StartPos)
'    For i = 5 To 64
'        If Asc(Mid(pData.Path, i, 1)) <> 0 Then
'            strSpoolFile = strSpoolFile & Mid(pData.Path, i, 1)
'        End If
'    Next
    On Error Resume Next
    FileCopy FileToPrint, strSpoolFile
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox Err.Number & " : " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "NSPrint"
        NSPrintFile = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    Success = ScheduleJob(phPrinter, JobId)
    If Success <> 1 Then
        MsgBox "Cannot Spool the Printer JobID !", vbExclamation, "NSPrint"
        NSPrintFile = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    Success = ClosePrinter(phPrinter)
    If Success <> 1 Then
        MsgBox "Cannot close the Printer !", vbExclamation, "NSPrint"
        NSPrintFile = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    If delAfterPrint = True Then Kill FileToPrint
    NSPrintFile = True
End Function
```

---

Note: The error message is "Cannot assign JobID !"

(This is the complete code used to call print function. The same code works fine for Win98 but, fails for Win7. Kindly give me a solution.)

Comment: I, for one, have no clue what you're asking.  Can you define "not working"? If there's an error, give the error message. If you haven't posted all the relevant code, please do so. For example, if `AddJob` is returning something other than 1, show the code for `AddJob`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you reply. Just now I edited the question with complete code. The error message is "Cannot assign JobID !"

Comment: For someone to answer you need to say how it doesn't work, rather than it doesn't work. Does it throw an error? If so, what is the number and message? Have you determined by stepping through the code in the debugger which line is failing? Add anything else that would help us determine the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion,Note: The error message is "Cannot assign JobID !"

Comment: What is the function AddJob ? and what is the value of Success after trying AddJob ?